# How to cancel Firebase setValue while pending for completion (when offline)

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I can call ref.removeAllObservers() for reading data (such as observeEventType) if I want to stop listening for real time changes. However, i cannot find a way to interrupt and cancel the setValue (writing data). There are some use case which I need to cancel the writing of data while waiting for some time for internet connection to get back online. Is it possible and how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there is a write queue, you can empty it by calling `FIRDatabase.purgeOutstandingWrites()`.

Comment: thanks so much, frank. i spent the whole day looking for the answer and it's not stated in any of the firebase official tutorial. Then u just solved my problem within an hour. Should have asked earlier.

Comment: The reference docs (while super-terse) are great for digging up the available methods. https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasedatabase/