# How to cancel firebase setValue() intentionaly for android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38352118/how-to-cancel-firebase-setvalue-while-pending-for-completion-when-offline) it was asked for swift but I have an exact same question for android, which is **how to cancel setValue() process when I want programmaticaly ?** To make the question more clear if I have a timer for the process when timer completes I want it to cancel any setValue() process .

Comment: you can use the same in android https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/FirebaseDatabase.html#purgeOutstandingWrites()

Comment: Thanks mate, the doc seems pretty solid .I will try and get back.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the same for android as well

[purgeOutstandingWrites](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/FirebaseDatabase#purgeOutstandingWrites())

> The Firebase Database client automatically queues writes and sends
>   them to the server at the earliest opportunity, depending on network
>   connectivity. `In some cases (e.g. offline usage) there may be a large`
>   `number of writes waiting to be sent. Calling this method will purge`
>   `all outstanding writes so they are abandoned.`
>
> `All writes will be purged, including transactions and onDisconnect()`
>   `writes. The writes will be rolled back locally`, perhaps triggering
>   events for affected event listeners, and the client will not (re-)send
>   them to the Firebase backend.